# Rhythmbox iPod Issues?

Tags: sync, rhythmbox, ipod

Basically, when I try and drag a song from my library to any one of my iPods (Classic (2.0.4 Mac), Touch (3.1.2. (7D11)) and Shuffle), nothing happens. It would appear that everything went ok, but when I go to the iPod's library, the song is not there. When trying to transfer the file, there is no error etc. to indicate what went wrong, and so I can't file a bug report on Launchpad etc.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I'm running a 64-bit install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS and that Amarok and gtkpod don't even recognise that any devices are plugged in. Thanks.

Comment: See this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPod

Comment: @beeju, I have had a read through that previously, and I should have mentioned that I have already tried to use gtkpod and Amarok, which simply don't recognise the devices. I should also have mentioned that I'm running a 64-bit install of 12.04LTS. Sorry!

Comment: I've same settings:
$ uname -a
Linux ElAtuel 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:30:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and same problem.

Comment: I tried installing gtkpod and ubuntu-restricted-extra nothing happened until I disabled the portable player plugins. Not sure what happend. I'll keep looking. Try disabling the plugins.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that on 10.10 (32bit) the above fix works:

```
apt-get install gtkpod ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Simply restart **Rhythmbox** and if the iPod doesn't auto recognize do the following:

> **[Music] → Scan Removable Media**

and give it a few moments: (mine took 3 minutes to index, not sure what it was doing but took a few moments before it showed up)

Also ensure in the plugins that iPod is ON:

> **[Edit] → Plugins → Portable Players - iPod**

I have a 6th Gen iPod classic 160GB.

> **[EDIT]:**

You can also after you verify all of the above, do the following if the iPod is still not showing up...

> **Simply** click **[Music]**  →  **[Import Folder]**  →  (On the left(in **Places**) of the new window you should see the connected iPod listed) Click the iPod, and **CLOSE** that window with **[Cancel]**  *(hopefully you'll see the iPod listed in **Devices** now.  :)

Comment: i have 12.04 at home (and confirmed this works there as well)

Comment: Worked perfectly on 12.04 64bits! Thank you!

Comment: Followed all these steps, but my ipod is still saying: "No music - You can sync music from iTunes." I have a 6th gen 8gb nano touch, and I'm running 12.04

Comment: worked on 16.04 but broken with 18.04